# Class not found when extended

Tags: php, extends, classnotfound

I have a `class MyClass` that works fine. When I create an instance using
`$obj = new MyClass()` works like a charm. The problem is, if I extend this `class MyClass extends MyExtends`, it gives me an error: *class MyClass not found*.

Because the devil is in the details, here are some:

1) MyClass instance is created in the same file (called MyClass.php).

```
$obj = new MyClass();
class MyClass extends MyExtends{
}
```

2) The creation of `obj` is called using ajax

```
if($_POST['myAjaxFlag']){
    $obj = new MyClass();
}
```

3) The ajax call returns as success, but if I print the data returned, I get that class not found error php message.

Comment: Where are you defining `MyExtends`? Can you post the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Is 1) and 2) happening in the same file?

Comment: client-side AJAX uses http status codes to determine success/failure. As long as the PHP side of things returns a 200, Javascript will assume success, even if the actual "success" was a total failure.

Comment: cant find your `MyExtends` class...

Comment: @iamnotmaynard MyExtends is defined in another file. I include this file at the beginning.

Comment: @TheWolf yes. I elaborated those 2 points separated, but is the same file. The if statment surround the instantiation, and the the class is declared.

Comment: Let's see the MyExtends declaration, and your require statement.  Then we'll all be able to play with it ourselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you declare the class "MyClass" after your initialisation

```
obj = new MyClass();
class MyClass extends MyExtends{

}
```

Corrected:

```
class MyClass extends MyExtends{
}
obj = new MyClass();
```

Should work then ;)

Comment: Thank you! I really don't know why this works, but it does. If I don't extend MyClass, it works even if it's before the class declaration.

Edit: I saw your response before your correction, and I assumed you wanted to change the order (without the first $obj = new MyClass();)

Comment: Yes, you are right, i have corrected my formatting ,
because it only one Codeblock so i have split in two . 
But Nice that it works

Answer (score 1):

Order matters:

```
<?php
    class Base
    {
        protected function sayHello()
        {
            echo("Base hello\n");
        }
    }

    class Child extends Base
    {
        public function sayHello()
        {
            parent::sayHello();

            echo("Child hello\n");
        }
    }

    $obj = new Child();
    $obj->sayHello();    

?>
```

> Base hello
>
> Child hello

Comment: MyExtends class is declared before MyClass declaration (using `require` at the top).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the class before you can use it.  So the "new" should come after the class MyClass definition.

Also MyExtends needs to be defined before you can extend it... either beforehand in the same file, or via a "require" statement.

Comment: I require the file where MyExtends is declared at the beginning, but still doesn't works.